# Trying to cast different types of data into a string in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, casting

I have quite a few data types inside a class I want to make into a string or a char array so I can write them in a file in the correct order. Currently trying to make an unsigned int into a char array or a string.

What I mean is to turn 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x31 == 10 into  == "\0\0\01". I've searched around and only found people turning 10 into "10".

Is there any practical way of doing that?

Comment: please show what you have so far in terms of code.

Comment: Are you looking for [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)?

Comment: Casts are not magic. You cannot just cast between unrelated types and expect to get anything sensible.

Comment: Sounds like you want to research the terms *serialization* and *de-serialization*.

Comment: The 4 bytes `0x0 0x0 0x0 0x31` is already the same as the string `"\0\0\01"`, so its not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what I done wrong:

I couldn't attribute a value to a string while declaring it like we can with primitive types.

What I did at first:

```
int i = 123;
string test = (char*)i; //or string test = i;
```

What I should've done:

```
int i = 123;
string test;
test = i;
```

Very basic mistake. Sorry for bothering you.